# Why is wpf application crashing only when launched through Explorer with command line arguments?

Tags: c#, wpf

Right now, I can launch the app through explorer (by double clicking its icon), I can run it through a command prompt *with* or *without* arguments, but if I try to launch it through explorer and also pass arguments, (such as by dragging a file onto it) it crashes.

[Process Explorer screenshot showing command line arguments when running from powershell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YgG7.png)

[image]

[Process Explorer screenshot showing command line arguments when running from explorer by draggin a file onto it. Notice how it crashes instantly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn0CG.png)

[image]

This is the code I am using to process command line arguments:

```
public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppMainWindow = new MainWindow();
    if (e.Args.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (File.Exists(e.Args[i]))
            {
                OpenDocument(e.Args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (File.Exists(Settings.Default.PreviousFile))
        {
            OpenDocument(Settings.Default.PreviousFile);
        }
    }
    AppMainWindow.Show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? Is there an error? Have you tried starting it using the commands in visual studio?

Comment: Don't you have to call `InitializeComponents()` on `AppMainWindow`?

Comment: The exception thrown when your program "crashes" will be a huge clue, but you'll have to tell us what that exception is.

Comment: Also, if you can get your images directly in your question, that would be good.

Comment: It "crashes" in that it quits unexpectedly. Nothing out of the ordinary in Visual Studio, because I cannot replicate the problem in VS. It only happens when launching through explorer

Comment: In you App class, add the method `private void h(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString()); }` and hook up the handler in the constructor `public App() { DispatcherUnhandledException += h; }` so you can see the error.

Comment: Add some error trapping to the code and see if you can catch something, and log/show it. Without an error, this is all guess work.

Comment: Thank you! That points to an error I would not have expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was a piece of code somewhere else that loaded an external file.

Original looked like this: `"Dictionaries/" + Settings.Default.DictionaryLanguage + ".aff"`

Fixed looks like this: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Dictionaries/" + Settings.Default.DictionaryLanguage + ".aff"`

I don't know why this didn't manifest at any other time, but that was the problem.